# trying to get values from text box, radio button and slider controls wpf.

Tags: c#, xaml, slider, radio-button, wpf-controls

hello I am trying to get values from 3 different control types (text box, Radio button and Slider) to compute a monthly payment for a loan. I am having trouble getting the value for the radio button and the slider.

There are 3 radio buttons for year(15,30, other) if other is checked then the user inputs the year in a text box.

The slider gathers the interest rate. I am unsure how to get the value that the user slides too.

The output should be in a label.

```
    private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    void radiobutton_CheckChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //txtYears.IsEnabled = btn3.IsChecked;
    }

    private void sldRate_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        double p, yrs, r, m;

        double.TryParse(txtPrin.Text, out p);

        foreach (RadioButton button in stkYears.Children)
        {
            if (button.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                if (button.Content.ToString() == "Other")
                    txtYears.IsEnabled = btn3.IsChecked;           
            }
        }
        double.TryParse(txtYears.Text, out yrs);

        m = (txtPrin *  )
            //the above statment should  look like this 
            //m = (p * r / 1200.0) / (1 - Math.Pow((1.0 + r / 1200.0), (-12 * yrs)));
        lblMonthlyPayment.TextInput = m.ToString();           

    }
```

below is the xaml

```
<Label Content="Number Of Years" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" FontFamily="NSimSun" FontSize="14" Height="26" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,28,0,0"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Name="stkYears" Margin="0,6,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
            <RadioButton x:Name="btn1" GroupName="Years" Content="15 Years" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Height="15" FontFamily="Shruti" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Years"  Content="30 Years" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Height="15" FontFamily="Shruti" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="btn3" GroupName="Years"  Checked="radioButton_CheckChanged" Unchecked="radioButton_CheckChanged" Content="Other" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,1,0,0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Height="15" FontFamily="Shruti" IsChecked="True"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtYears" Height="17" Margin="30,0,168,0"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Label Content="Interest Rate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="188" FontFamily="NSimSun" FontSize="14" Height="24" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="sldRate" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
             AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="3"
             AutoToolTipPrecision="2" IsDirectionReversed="False"
             IsMoveToPointEnabled="False" Margin="13,27,-18,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291" Minimum="0" Maximum="6" Ticks="0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" ValueChanged="sldRate_ValueChanged" Height="51" Background="White" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="#00000000" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>



        <Button Name ="btnSubmit" Content="Calculate Monthly Payment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" Click="btnSubmit_Click" Height="30" Grid.Row="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblMonthlyPayment" Content="" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,15,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" IsEnabled="False" />
```

Comment: "Having trouble" in what way?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @PhilGref How do I get the value for the radio button and slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer for question 1:**

Enabling textbox, when other radio button `IsChecked="true"`

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtYears" Height="17" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=btn3,Path=IsChecked}" Margin="30,0,168,0"/>
```

**Answer for question 2:**

**To get slider value in code behind**

```
double value = System.Convert.ToDouble(sldRate.TickFrequency.ToString());
```

In xaml,

```
       <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="sldRate" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
                     AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="3"
                     AutoToolTipPrecision="2" IsDirectionReversed="False"
                     IsMoveToPointEnabled="False" Margin="23,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" 
                      ValueChanged="sldRate_ValueChanged" Height="51" 
Background="White" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="#00000000"/>
```

**Answer for question 3:**

**Get value based on Radio button IsChecked in code behind**

```
double years;
            if(btn1.IsChecked == true)
            {
                years = 15;
            }
            else if(btn2.IsChecked == true)
            {
                years = 30;
            }
            else if(btn3.IsChecked == true)
            {
                years = System.Convert.ToDouble(txtYears.Text);
            }
```

Note: If you are seriously coding for enterprise level application, Follow MVVM pattern. Don't use classic winform code behind pattern.
Learn MVVM and databinding concepts in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the textbox when the radio button is checked you need to  bind the IsEnabled property of the TextBox to the IsChecked property of the Radio button:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtYears" Height="17" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=btn3,Path=IsChecked}" Margin="30,0,168,0"/>
```

To get the value of slider you just need to access its value using its name in the code behind file like this:

```
var sliderValue = sldRate.Value.ToString()
```